# stop php from wrapping individual echo lines of report in a narrow browser window

Tags: php, css

Inside a PHP loop:

```
 echo $[whatever 1]." ".$[whatever 1]." ".[n]." ".$[whatever 20];
 echo "<br>";
```

It outputs and writes fine, but whenever I subsequently narrow the browser window after the generation, the lines of that report start wrapping inside the browser.  I want them instead to remain collinear and just disappear beyond the right edge of the browser.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap them in an element with the `white-space:nowrap;` property:

```
echo '<div class="myClass">'.$[whatever 1].' '.$[whatever 1].' '.[n].' '.$[whatever 20].'</div>';
```

css:

```
.myClass {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

Comment: you probably don't need to echo an extra `<br/>` if it's in a div